# Running npm script from Python script. Getting inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I have a directory containing some python scripts.  In this directory there are subdirectories in the form of 'a/b/c1', 'a/b/c2', ..., 'a/b/cn', etc.  Each of these directories is an npm package with a script in the `package.json` file called `my_script`.

From the directory with my python scripts I can run the following command from the terminal fine:

`npm run my_script --prefix a/b/c1`

However in my python script I doing something along the lines the following:

```
bashCmd = ['npm', 'run', 'my_script', '--prefix', 'a/b/c1']
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
print(error)
```

The result of `output` is the message from npm telling you instructions on arguments to pass to it.

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,...
```

From what I can tell, I am running the same set of instructions, one from Python, and one from npm, but getting different results.

Can anybody help me shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I might have been looking at some older documentation or plain misinterpreted what I was reading for `subprocess.Popen()`.  I was under the impression the input passed to this function was supposed to be a list of strings where each string would normally be separated by a space if you were to type the command directly into the terminal.  If you just take the normal command and pass this as input like below, the program executes correctly.

```
bashCmd = ['npm run my_script --prefix a/b/c1']
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
print(error)
```